# How to get the xml data between the nodes?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using .Net web service in my Android app.The service return the values between the Message tag like this:

```
<Message> CustomerID=10 </Message>
```

Here, how can i take the data from this Message tag using Android?

I want to retrieve the information inside the xml received from the web service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your code. Also consider editing your question. The result is CostumerID=10 and you want the output CostumerID=10, so, there's no problem?

Comment: I put it the first CustomerID=10 between the message tag.But it's not the browser...Again i'll give the sample data as this,<Message>CustomerID=10</Message>
<Message>Alternate PhoneNo=123456789</Message>How can i get the data's from this Message tag?
<Message>CustomerName=xxxxx</Message>
<Message>Address1=yyyyy</Message>

Comment: So, the problem is how to parse an xml in java. That's pretty different from the question you asked.

Answer (score 2):

example for parsing `xml`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db;
try {
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = null;
    doc = db.parse([InputStream]);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Message");
    if (nl != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node item = nl.item(i);
            String name = item.getNodeName();
            String value = item.getTextContent();
        }
    }
}catch{}
```

You will get the value between the tags with

```
item.getTextContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this example u will get  your solution.
You doesn't worry about Tag that will be handle by Default Handler 
Only u want to declare Starting Tag 
[SAX Sample](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser)  only change tag ...